# How to mmap character device file?

Tags: c, linux

How can I use `mmap` to map a character device file to my application? I've tried the following code which fails because the size of the file is zero (`sb.st_size == 0`). Is there another way or is this impossible all together? Thanks.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int init_module(void *module_image, unsigned long len,
                    const char *param_values);

int main() {
  int res = 0;
  void *buf = 0;
  struct stat sb;
  int rc = 0;

  int fd = open("/dev/nvidia0", O_RDWR);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  res = fstat(fd, &sb);
  if (res == -1) {
    perror("fstat");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  buf = mmap(0, sb.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (buf == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  munmap(buf, sb.st_size);
  close(fd);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You can't. it is a character device and thus not seekable.

Comment: @wildplasser A simple Google search reveals that `/dev/nvidia*` supports `mmap` and `fcntl` (and nothing else).

Comment: you mean `sb.st_size == 0` so `mmap` is setting errno to `EINVAL`?

Comment: @Rhymoid was there any example? What were your search terms? Thanks.

Comment: In my limited experience with `mmap`ing, I've `mmap`ed to FPGA devices over PCIe. `lspci` revealed their BAR address ranges, and then I would open `/dev/mem` and `mmap` the BAR starting address with the length of the range. No idea if this is relevant or not, but any chance your `/dev/nvidia0` device has some IO memory in the system?

Comment: I didn't find code examples, but the capabilities are mentioned on [the OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Accelerated_Graphic_Cards). I also saw something about [a privilege escalation vulnerability that involved `mmap`ing `/dev/nvidia*`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/959842), but I couldn't find the exploit mentioned. I *did* figure out that [`/dev/mem` is a character device too](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl4_mem.htm), but that doesn't tell us which byte range to `mmap` from "within" `/dev/nvidia0`.

Comment: @yano, I'm not sure. I did some searching but found nothing. I'm new to `mmap`ing with devices.

Comment: `cat /proc/iomem` may provide some hints, if you can find your device in there. Also if you look at `dmesg` output you may see linux assign some memory to it at bootup (at least you can with PCIe devices). My end game here is to access it using `/dev/mem` like I did with the FPGAs but that could be totally off, I'm no linux master. The fact that you have a device for it suggests to me that accessing it via `/dev/mem` is not the way to go anyway. Where did that device come from, did you install a driver or something?

Comment: Running strace on glxgears, I get `mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 5, 0xf2060000) = 0x7fe2c7649000` (where 5 is the fd returned by an open of /dev/nvidia0). The two obvious differences are the offset and the lack of `PROTO_EXEC`. I believe the mmap ability of a device is determined by the driver, so it might be that the NVIDIA driver doesn't support PROT_EXEC, requires the proper offset, or needs some ioctls to be called first. I wouldn't imagine you'd need PROT_EXEC anyway, as that would allow you to execute device memory as code.

Comment: @rkjnsn Heisenbug was also trying to `mmap` with size (2nd argument) of zero. Where did you get 4096 from?

Comment: @yano The mmap call is from strace on glxgears to see what the NVIDIA library does. There's a bunch of ioctls prior to that call though, on both /dev/nvidiactl and /dev/nvidia0. (Both files are opened and mmap'd.)

Comment: @rkjnsn ohhh I got you now, thanks